# backbone collections' population with server data

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone collection. I fetch. The server comes back with a JSON. How do I populate the collection witht he fresh data? Here's my code:

```
    var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({

       url: "server/todos-service.php", // this does what it is supposed to do so no worries!

       model: Todo,   

       initialize: function(attributes, options) {    
           // IN HERE WHAT DO I HAVE TO DO?
           // WHAT EVENT SHALL I BIND TO TO REACT THE DATA DELIVERY?
           // AND WHAT SHALL I DO NEXT TO POPULATE THE DAMN THINGS

           }
        });

    // CLIENT CODE
    new Todos().fetch();
```

Can anyone tell me how this is supposed to be done?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetch` will start the ajax call to your server. When the data is returned it is automatically put the data into your collection, and the collection will fire a `reset` being like "I'm done fetching data bro, you can use it now."

You would usually call fetch() from inside your view, and have the view listen to the `reset` event. When the reset event is trigger, the view renders the collection.

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // my model
});

var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     url: myurl
     model: Todo   
    // my collection (usually nothing in the initialize function) 
});


var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    // instantiate the collection
    this.collection = new TodoList();

    //listen to the reset event on the collection. When the reset event trigger, call the render function.
    this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);

    // get the data from the backend
    this.collection.fetch();
  },
  render: function() {
     // render the collection like a boss
  }
});

//instantiate the view 
var App = new AppView;
```

Also as a resource, I found this tutorial to be really helpful in understanding the basics of backbone http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js/

Comment: I agree, I don't ever do this but thats whats in most of the ToDo examples for simplicity's sake. I guess I'll update it haha